# Android Bluetooth (BLE) corrupted data on onCharacteristicChanged

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

**My app do the following:**

1. It sends a command with `onDescriptorWrite` to the BT device.
2. As soon the BT device gets this command **it starts transferring data** to the Android phone.
3. Android's `onCharacteristicChanged` is **catching all the data** sent from the BT device.
4. After all the data is transferred the Android app writes it to a file.

I've tested it **and everything works totally perfect on a Samsung (Android 11), a OnePlus (Android 11), and a Xiaomi (Android 9)**, but the  data coming from `onCharacteristicChanged` is **getting corrupted on a Nokia (Android 11).**

This test example shows the transferred data wrote into a file with a checksum. **As you can see I get the very same bytes on a Xiaomi, but on the Nokia it sometimes gets corrupted.**

```
Tested on Xiaomi MiA1 (Android 9)

File_MD5: The right file MD5 -> AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85

File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: AE36F08213B25B5E0EE19425257D0D85 (ok)


Tested on Nokia 5.4 (Android 11)

File_MD5: The right file MD5 -> BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8

File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: E65A5D38EB3D8BF4E1AF5240DFBE1840 (ERROR)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: 0D3A577631A115FBAF3324A9B09244A8 (ERROR)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: A6FB1334D7AA1520F105ACB1EC1324C5 (ERROR)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8 (ok)
File_MD5: Measurement file MD5: BCF704DD811A760B5602C20DEDB61AF8 (ok)
```

---

I'm absolutely standing incomprehensibly in front of this issue, **yet another one of Android's fragmented and unreliable ecosystem.**

---

**I've tried the following:**

1. Setting my `BluetoothGatt` instance to `CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH` mode with `requestConnectionPriority`
2. Using a `synchronized` data container in `onCharacteristicChanged` in case if this is some multiple thread writing the same container type of error.

None of them helped.

Any insights?

**E D I T:**

My coworker made a firmware which **simply sends incrementing numbers.** As you can see within the red area, **the data is corrupted, even with** [Nordic's own nRF toolbox app.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox)

### Should I be worried?

That means this Nokia is just doesn't work and that is it? Can this be a hardware issue for only this device?

[image]

Comment: How does your onCharacteristicChanged look like? You don't need to use synchronized in there. Callback for the next notification will not arrive until you have returned in the previous callback. It can also be a good idea to check the hci snoop log on the Android device to see if the contents look correct there.

Comment: The results are the same whether I use or don't use synchronized. What is "hci snoop log" may I ask?

Comment: Is it Android Api level independent? What about the other models? (Samsung,  OnePlus) Which Android version are they running?

Comment: have you tried with BluetoothGattServer to see if the behaviour is same on both devices? You have same kind of methods like onDescriptorWriteRequest, onCharacteristicReadRequest, onCharacteristicWriteRequest

Comment: @ddassa I don't really understand your question, the post is about that I have tried in 4 different devices an on 3 works perfect but on one doesn't.

Comment: Just google "hci snoop log" and you will find out how to capture it.

Comment: @Emil I did it, the snoop log thing is deprecated, there is a bugreport.txt instead on Android 11. It has nothing which can provide me an information about any error.

Comment: Snoop log is not deprecated, they have just changed the way how it is accessed between different versions. I think https://medium.com/@charlie.d.anderson/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-host-controller-interface-logs-from-a-modern-android-phone-d23bde00b9fa should be up to date. You should also use an air sniffer (nrf devkit can be used as sniffer) which will then verify if the data is corrupted over HCI.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are some differences in the realisation on that smartphone.   Try to do these things:

1. Put each chunks of the data (retrieved from `onCharacteristicChanged`) to a thread safe collection. It'll be better to wrap each chunk in a structure (`{data: ByteArray, device: *, something else...}`).
2. Handle each chunk in a background thread to avoid the UI freezing.
   The main reason to do it, some devices are actively using byte caches inside and that could corrupt the data, we should copy bytes from `onCharacteristicChanged` as soon as possible and them handle in a convenient way on our own thread.

Comment: As I wrote in my question I already tried that. The problem is that even the byte[] param which comes from onCharChanged is already corrupted.

Comment: Probably the problem is deeper than I thought, try to catch HCI logs ( https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/verifying_debugging ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, byte corruption can and does happen. I observed this on various devices most partiuclar cheap phones (e.g. ZTE Blade 512, Vivo Y20).
For my analysis I usually compare the btsnoop_hci.log (from Android) and a sniffer log (I use a frontline BPA).
When I run a test, I'll do echo test with incrementing numbers between phone and peripheral. In our usecase the connection is always encrypted via Ble Enhanced Security.

Issues I saw:

1. Notification Payload is corrupted, random values
2. Notification Payload is appended to wrong HCI Packets.

Number 1: the issue you are facing and indeed must happen somewhere in the stack, and is usually already visible in hci.log.
It must happen within the phone after the packet was received, as BLE does have MIC for the encrypted part and CRC within for the payload. So if corrpution would happen over air this 2 checks would already fail. Since the packet is correct in SnifferLog and corrupted in hci.log we can conclude an issue within the phone
Number 2:
Sometimes I see the actual payload of a notification appended to an ATT_WRITE_RESPONSE, in this case after a Write_Request I saw 2 WriteResponses were only 1 should have been +1 Notification. The extra write response had the DataPayload of the Notification, which was expected and visibile in SnifferLog
Again MIC and CRC should have taken care of this.

**Possible Workarounds**:
Implement CRC checks for Notifications on Application level, so the notification not only include the status value but also a CRC.
Make characteristic Read/Notify (this may require FW changes on your peripheral), so in case of CRC for notifications is wrong you can still read.

If you are using Notifications as RX Channel on a message protocol. Implement high level integrity check + retransmission.
Yes this may be a hard sell to PM since BLE should have this already, but not the stack inbetween.

Could you specify your Nokia phone? I might want to add it to my testing setup. I saw issues with Nokia phones but never of this kind.

Comment: Sure, it is a "Nokia 5.4"

Here: https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_us/nokia-5-4?sku=HQ5020M515000